# Three Dimensional Boolean Arrays In Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
public class Map {
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int x, y, z;
    private boolean[][][] blocks;
    /**
     * Creates a map object. Map objects include a 3 dimensional 
     * boolean array. Declared through <code>new boolean[z][y][x]</code>.
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param z 
     */
    public Map(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.blocks = new boolean[this.z][this.y][this.x];
        for (boolean[][] i : this.blocks) {
            for (boolean[] j : i) {
                for(int k = 0; k < j.length; k++) {
                    j[k] = (rand.nextInt(1) == 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.blocks));
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns the map array.
     * @return 
     */
    public String getMap() {
        return Arrays.toString(blocks);
    }
}
```

I want to create a three-dimensional boolean array of random true/false values. However, whenever I call `new Map(10, 10, 10)` I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException", which means that the array is either full of null values, or is null itself.

What I want to know is how can I create this array, so I do not get this exception (nor any other exception).

EDIT: I fixed an error with setting a value for `rand`, but the loops still do not fill the array with booleans. I get this:

```
[[[Z@6d06d69c, [[Z@7852e922, [[Z@4e25154f, [[Z@70dea4e, [[Z@5c647e05, [[Z@33909752, [[Z@55f96302, [[Z@3d4eac69, [[Z@42a57993, [[Z@75b84c92]
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate `rand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your array is not really 3D, it is an [array of array of arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). So your line

```
this.blocks = new boolean[this.z][this.y][this.x];
```

creates an array of z instances of boolean[][], all of which are null. So we need to create them explicitely:

```
    this.blocks = new boolean[z][y][x];
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        this.blocks[i] = new boolean[y][x];
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            this.blocks[i][j] = new boolean[x];
            for(int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                this.blocks[i][j][k] = (rand.nextInt(1) == 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.blocks));
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get this: `[[[Z@6d06d69c, [[Z@7852e922, [[Z@4e25154f, [[Z@70dea4e, [[Z@5c647e05, [[Z@33909752, [[Z@55f96302, [[Z@3d4eac69, [[Z@42a57993, [[Z@75b84c92]`

Comment: I don't think Arrays.ToString can deal with multidimensional arrays. Try debugging/printing it another way (sorry, not used to Java anymore).

Comment: You were right. Arrays.ToString does not do multidimensional arrays, however, I was able to do Arrays.DeepToString().